Triangle problem when sides are given in linear expression form as $x,y$ variables
I got another question from geometry in my telegram group of teaching aspirants :
The sides of a triangle are $3x + 4 y, 4 x + 3 y$ and $5 x + 5y$ and $x,y<0$ then the triangle is
a): obtuse angled
b): right angled
c): equilateral
d): none
My answer is D as all the given sides passes through the origin and negative side they didn't intersected. But the given answer is A. It can be wrong or misprint. Am I missing any important think in the question please let me know

I don't understand the question. What does a side being $3x+4y$ mean? Does it mean the equation $3x+4y=0$?

I would assume the sides are expressions of length, not equations since they have no constant term. I think you need a combination of Pythagoras and inequalities (if $c^2>a^2+b^2$ what does that mean about the largest angle?)

Yes right equation

@RedFive btw can I contact you?  I'm from India and I am looking for a job in Australia as a primary school teacher

@RedFive: But $a,b<0$ is given. So, ...?

Thanks sir. I am also confused in selecting long side as x,y<0 if it was >0 then i could clearly say 5x+5y is big but it is different case. I have attached the picture of the question for more clarity

The answer is a.
